# Does SonarQube calculates "Effort to reach Maintainability Rating A" considering code duplication?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, code-duplication, sonarqube-scan

it looks like that out-of-the-box SonarQube 6 (6.3.1) does not consider the time to fix "Duplicated Code" and "Comments" when presenting the effort in the "Effort to reach Maintainability Rating A" metric. Is that correct?

If so, is there a way to add in the effort the time needed to fix duplicated code and/or lack of comments (%) ? I see there is a rule "Source files should not have any duplicated blocks" that can be activated. Is that all is needed to calculate time to fix duplicated code?

Does technical debt also accounts for comments ?

Sonar documentation does not state how "Effort to reach Maintainability Rating A" metric is calculated in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Maintainability Rating is based on the Technical Debt
- Technical Debt is the sum of the estimated remediation time of all Code Smells
- Code Smell issues are raised by the Code Smell rules included in the profile

To include coverage and duplications in your Maintainability Rating, include the relevant rules. The rest will happen automatically.

Comment: Sorry, my question was directed more to how sonar calculates the "**Effort to reach** Maintainability Rating A" than the rating itself. For instance, 3days and 4hours to reach maintanability rating is the sum of Code Smells issue only? Or does it add time to dedupe code as well?

Comment: @GiovaniS. only if your profile includes duplications rules

Comment: There are rules to detect comments that match certain patterns, but there's know what of knowing statically how much time it will take to address them.